# How do you mark backlog items as "ready" in Jira?

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

Using the Agile Scrum methodology, stories that are `ready` from the backlog can be moved into a sprint

There is generally a process to agree when a story has been sufficiently refined to be considered `ready`

How do you indicate this in `Jira`?

My backup plan is to just have an undated sprint named "Ready", and then move `ready` stories from the backlog to "Ready" to a dated sprint, but that seems messy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is to use backlog refinement sessions to decide which stories are 'ready'.

For example, you could have a backlog refinement session planned several days before the end of a sprint. In that session the Product Owner would present the stories they would like to target for the next sprint. The team reviews the stories and points out any potential problems with adding them to the next sprint. At that point the Product Owner could mark stories as 'ready' if they found that useful. Other stories might require a bit more preparation work and the Product Owner has the days until planning to do this in.

I've seen a couple of approaches to recording the 'ready' state. One is to have a 'ready' column in Jira. Another possible approach is to use a radio button style custom field called 'ready'. That would allow you to add in a quick filter to the backlog view in Jira agile that would give you the ability to only show stories that are ready at the planning session.

Answer (score 1):

I think the process of agreeing wether or not a story is 'ready', is sprint planning.

Sprint planning gives developers the opportunity to dig into the story, and ask questions from the product owner, and decide it's readiness. If the product owner isn't able to make the story clear during planning, then it's not ready. The acid test for readiness though, in my opinion, is wether or not developers are comfortable giving an estimate to the story.

Reflecting this status in jira is another matter. In the past I edited the Jira workflow, and added additional state 'ready to estimate', but I've since removed it, it didn't add much value but increased complexity.

I think you should be aiming for the majority of stories that make it into sprint planning to be clearly defined and ready to estimate, but it's fine if there are a few there which aren't, so long as the planning session doesn't turn into a 'design the feature' session. Someone needs to call the fact that it's not ready, and toss it from planning.

Tim